# I need to create function which take value from string and edit numbers

Tags: javascript, string, hex, decimal

I have this string 03.00.20.80.0F.00.00.68.98.01. last two bytes 98.01. have information about temperature.
I need to create JavaScript function which convert two last bytes from hexadecimal number 0198 to 19 and 8.
This numbers I want to convert from hexadecimal numbers to decimal and sum together. So it gives me number 25.8. It must be variable for whatever number because I can receive other string from my sensor like 03.00.20.80.0F.00.00.54.09.02.

I tried this function but it is return value 0.1

```js
function splitAndConvertHex(hexString) {
  
  const bytes = hexString.split('.');
  
  const lastTwoBytes = bytes.slice(-2).join('');
  
  const hexValue = '0x' + lastTwoBytes;
  
  const intValue = parseInt(hexValue) >> 8;
  const floatValue = (parseInt(hexValue) & 0xFF) / 10;

  return [intValue, floatValue];
}

const hexString = "03.00.20.80.0F.00.00.68.98.01.";
const [wholeNumber, decimalNumber] = splitAndConvertHex(hexString);

const result = wholeNumber + decimalNumber;
console.log("Výsledek: " + result);
```

Comment: How are you getting from 98.01 to 0198 ? Are you inverting the values ? In your example, you are trying to converse 9801 into hex, which is 152, so I'm unsure where you are going with this.

Comment: 0 represents a positive temperature value 
19 represents the integer value of the temperature 
8 represents the decimal number of the temperature

Comment: I understand that, but the values in your byte array is "98.01". How do you get from "98.01" to "0198". Do you simply invert the values and concatenate them ? It seams illogical that the value "19" would be split into two bytes.

Comment: I have this information from datasheet. 
Following the issuance of
the Convert T [44h] command, a temperature conversion is performed and the thermal data is stored in
the scratchpad memory in a 16-bit, sign-extended two’s complement format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the logic behind getting `25.8` from `98.01`, but this produces the correct value:

```js
function splitAndConvertHex(hexString) {
  // "03.00.20.80.0F.00.00.68.98.01" --> 198
  let x = parseInt(hexString.split('.').slice(-2).reverse().join(''));
  return [parseInt((x / 10).toString(), 16), parseInt((x % 10).toString(), 16)];
}

console.log(splitAndConvertHex("03.00.20.80.0F.00.00.68.98.01"));
```

Comment: This answer is great, but I can not no longer work with result beacause it is array and I need float number.

Comment: @MarekPrachař Your code in the OP returned an array: `return [intValue, floatValue];` Anyway, it's easy to convert to a float.

Comment: Sorry I am not programmer. I don´t understand now.

Answer (score 0):

as I understood from your question I think the code should look like this:

```js
// Define a function that takes a hexadecimal string as input
function hexToTemp(hexString) {
  // Get the last two bytes of the string
  let lastTwoBytes = hexString.slice(-5);
  // Split the bytes into two parts
  let firstByte = lastTwoBytes.slice(0, 2);
  let secondByte = lastTwoBytes.slice(3);
  // Convert the bytes from hexadecimal to decimal
  let firstDecimal = parseInt(firstByte, 16);
  let secondDecimal = parseInt(secondByte, 16);
  // Sum the decimals and divide by 10 to get the temperature
  let temp = (firstDecimal + secondDecimal) / 10;
  // Return the temperature
  return temp;
}
// Test the function with an example string
let exampleString = "03.00.20.80.0F.00.00.68.98.01";
let exampleTemp = hexToTemp(exampleString);
console.log(exampleTemp); // the output is 15.3
```

I'm not sure this will answer your question but you can try it and if you have any questions or comments let me know

Comment: This example is good, thanks for your time but function don´t reverse 9801 to 0198 so result is wrong